# x-show elements based on parent element class in Alpine.js

Tags: javascript, woocommerce, alpine.js

In my WooCommerce theme, I'm want to show the spinner icon when WooCommerce dynamically adds the "loading" class to the  element using AJAX.

I tried to use Alpine.js's $el property to retrieve the current DOM node, but this isn't working. It's also not 'watching' the classList of .

How can I accomplish this using Alpine.js?

```
<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?>" class="ajax_add_to_cart add_to_cart_button single_add_to_cart_button button alt flex justify-center" data-product_id="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">

    <!-- Spinner Icon -->
    <svg x-show="$el.parentElement.classList.contains('loading')" class="animate-spin py-1 h-7 w-7 text-white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        ...
    </svg>

    <!-- Toevoegen aan winkelmand -->
    <span x-show="$el.parentElement.classList.contains('!loading')">
        <?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?>
    </span>
    
</button>
```

Comment: This method is not working because the classList is not reactive. You need to attach event listeners to the events dispatched by the loading function. Could you show the function doing the AJAX call?

Comment: I'm using the WooCommerce classes: ajax_add_to_cart add_to_cart_button, which enable the AJAX functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging into [WooCommerce source code](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/legacy/js/frontend/add-to-cart.js) revealed that it uses jQuery event system so we have to create a little event bus between jQuery and Alpine.js. The two respective events are `adding_to_cart` that called before the AJAX call and the `added_to_cart` event that triggered after the successful AJAX call (i.e. the product has been added to the cart).

Let's call our event bus `catchWooEvents`:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
    Alpine.data('catchWooEvents', () => ({
        loading: false,

        init() {
            $(document.body).on('adding_to_cart', (event, button, data) => {
                this.loading = true
            })
            $(document.body).on('added_to_cart', (fragments, cart_hash, button) => {
                this.loading = false
            })
        }
    }))
})
</script>
```

We have a new variable `loading` that is active between the two events. You see that we used the jQuery's `$.on()` function inside the `init()` to catch the jQuery events, but then we manipulate an Alpine.js variable.

The modified button example:

```
<div x-data="catchWooEvents">
    <button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?>" class="ajax_add_to_cart add_to_cart_button single_add_to_cart_button button alt flex justify-center" data-product_id="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">

        <!-- Spinner Icon -->
        <svg x-show="loading" class="animate-spin py-1 h-7 w-7 text-white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            ...
        </svg>

        <!-- Toevoegen aan winkelmand -->
        <span x-show="!loading">
            <?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?>
        </span>
        
    </button>
</div>
```

We have a new parent div element where we applied the `catchWooEvents` component, so multiple child buttons can share the loading state. In the `x-show` attribute the `loading` variable is now reactive.

Note: the definition of `catchWooEvents` must be placed after the jQuery script line.